# How do I create a downloadable excel sheet from an HTML-table?

Tags: javascript, php, html, excel, html-table

I have a table in HTML, like this:

```
<table>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Column1</th>
   <th>Column2</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>Data1</td>
   <td>Data2</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

I want to download this data in the form of an Excel-sheet. I've tried some "simple" methods of just opening the data in a new window like this:

```
javascript:window.open('data:application/vnd.ms-excel,'+document.documentElement.innerHTML);
```

But the actual table I want to export has too many lines and it crashes the browser..

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Clarification: I want to do this through a webpage, for examble using a button to trigger a function to create the excel sheet and start downloading it. Like this:

```
<button onclick="downloadExcelSheet()">Download the table as an excel sheet</button>
```

Comment: Try using CSV. You'll need to convert your data as CSV. Excel can display CSV data, try saving a normal spreadsheet as CSV to see the format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is off of a web server, you want to use the PHP Excel library

It can be found here: http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

If for some reason you don't have the ability to run PHP scripts, please include more information in your post

Comment: Thanks! Something like this is what I want. How do I trigger the download of the created excel sheet if I do a POST to the .php file running the PHPExcel script? I can't do a GET since I have to pass a large amount of data..

Comment: Just have it run inside an IF statement that checks that the form was posted.

Answer (score 0):

I took your posted data and pasted it into NotePad.  I saved the file from NotePad on my Desktop as sample.xls

I then double-clicked sample.xls.

First Excel complained about the file format, but then was able to open the file successfully.

**NOTE**:

I am using Office 2007 on Win7
The experiment failed if I used a .xlsx extension

Comment: Thanks, but that´s not what I mean, I want to create a webpage with a javascript function to trigger the creation and download of an excel sheet containing data from a table on the webpage.. I tried to clarify my original post also.